# I can send message to socket server and its print the output but can't recieve from the socket server to client in nodejs

Tags: node.js, next.js, socket.io

**I am Creating a chat application everything is almost done I can send messages and the server is receiving the data but can't receive the data from the socket.io server
basically, I created a separate server that connects the clients it didn't connect to the database. I tried everything but couldn't help**

---

```
                                     SocketServer.js
```

---

```
const io = require('socket.io')(9739, {
cors: {
    origin: "*",
    }
})

let activeUsers = [];

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   console.log('New user connected');

   socket.on('login', (data) => {
       console.log(data);
       if (!activeUsers.some((user) => user.id === data)) {
           activeUsers.push({
               id: data,
               socketId: socket.id
           });
       }
       // remove the active user that id is null
       activeUsers = activeUsers.filter((user) => user.id !== null);
       console.log(activeUsers);
       io.emit('activeUsers', activeUsers);
   });

  socket.on("sendMessage",(data)=>{
      const { receiverId } = data;
      const receiver = activeUsers.find((user) => user.id === receiverId);
      console.log("Sending Message to : ", receiver);
      console.log(data);
      if(receiver){
          console.log("comming")
          console.log(receiver.socketId);
          // send message to the receiver
          const RSocketId = receiver.socketId;
          console.log("RSocketId", RSocketId);
          io.to(RSocketId).emit("getMessage", { 
              data: data,
          });
      } 
  });

  socket.on("end", () => {
      console.log("end");
      socket.disconnect();
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('User disconnected');
      activeUsers = activeUsers.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socket.id);
      console.log(activeUsers);
      io.emit('activeUsers', activeUsers);
  });
 });
```

---

```
                                     Client Side
```

---

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import nookies from "nookies";
import Index from "./index";
import FriendsHolder from "../../components/Holders/FriendsHolder";
import FriendsDetails from "../../components/Holders/details-chats-holders/FriendsDetails";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import DmsComponent from "../../components/Holders/details-chats-holders/DmsComponent";
import { userDetails } from "../../libs/chats";
import SetUserName from "../../models/SetUserName";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const friends = ({ token }: any) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const [username, setusername] = React.useState(false);

  const [sendMsg, setSendMsg] = React.useState(null);

  const [receivedMsg, setReceivedMsg] = React.useState(null);

  const socket = useRef<any>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      const { data } = await userDetails(token);
      if (
        data &&
        (data.data.username.length > 20 || data.data.username === "")
      ) {
        setusername(true);
      } else {
        setusername(false);
        socket.current = io("ws://localhost:9739");
        socket?.current.emit("login", data.data?.id);
        socket?.current.on("activeUsers", (users: any) => {
          console.log("active users", users);
        });
      }
    };

    if (token) {
      init();
    }
  }, []);

  const handleLoading = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  const handleNotLoading = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleNotLoading();
  }, [isLoading]);

  // Sending message through the socket server
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (sendMsg !== null) {
      socket.current?.emit("sendMessage", sendMsg);
    }
  }, [sendMsg]);

  // Recieving Message through the socket server
  React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.current?.on("getMessage", (data: any) => {
      setReceivedMsg(data);
    });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(receivedMsg);
  }, [receivedMsg]);

  return (
    <Index>
      {username ? (
        <SetUserName />
      ) : (
        <>
          <FriendsHolder data={token} handleLoading={handleLoading} />
          {router.asPath === "/app/friends" && <FriendsDetails token={token} />}
          {router.asPath === `/app/friends?id=${router.query.id}` &&
            !isLoading && (
              <DmsComponent token={token} setSendMsg={setSendMsg} />
            )}
        </>
      )}
    </Index>
  );
};

export default friends;

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: any) => {
  const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
  const token = cookies.token;

  if (!token) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/?login",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      token: token || null,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: `socket.current?.on("getMessage", (data: any) => {
      setReceivedMsg(data);
    });`
this does not need to have an seperate `useEffect` if the dependencies are same.

Comment: can you tell which all logs are you getting?
for example the log in server at line 10.

Comment: @CircuitPlanet bro it displays the logged user

Comment: @CircuitPlanet i didn't understand what you are saying before the message

Comment: instead of `React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.current?.on("getMessage", (data: any) => {
      setReceivedMsg(data);
    });
  }, []);`
you should use it after `socket?.current.on("activeUsers", (users: any) => {
          console.log("active users", users);
        });`